# Actor example on page 699 in book "Programming in Scala" throws too many arguments error

Tags: scala

Code from the book:

```
object NameResolver extends Actor{
    import java.net.{InetAddress, UnknownHostException}

    def act(){
        react{
            case(name:String, actor:Actor) =>
                actor ! getIp(name)
                act()
            case "EXIT" => 
                println("Name resolver is exiting.")//quit
            case msg =>
                println("Unhandled message: "+msg)
                act()
        }
    }

    def getIp(name:String):Option[InetAddress]={
        try{
            Some(InetAddress.getByName(name))
        } catch {
            case _ : UnknownHostException => None
        }
    }

}
```

Interpreter line:

```
NameResolver ! ("http://stackoverflow.com", self)
```

But I got error:

```
scala> NameResolver ! ("http://stackoverflow.com", self)
<console>:8: error: too many arguments for method !: (msg: Any)Unit
              NameResolver ! ("http://stackoverflow.com", self)
```

According to the book, It's supposed to work. Is there an error in the code that I copy from the book that would cause the exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to pass a tuple, but the compiler thinks you're invoking `!` with two arguments. Because you can omit parenthesis sometimes, sometimes a tuple needs extra parenthesis like in `((1, 2))`. This may cause confusion. Try `NameResolver !(("http://stackoverflow.com", self))`

Comment: Or use the arrow syntax for creating tuples: `1->2`